# Pig command issue 'Failed to read data from "/pigdata/student"'

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

While running `dump` command for a relation a not returning any record ,it gives:

Test File:`student`

```
vineet  1 
hisham  2 
raj 3 
ajeet   4 
sujit 5 
ramesh  6 
priya   7 
priyanka    8 
suresh  9   
ritesh  10
```

Counters:

```
Total records written : 0
Total bytes written : 0
Spillable Memory Manager spill count : 0
Total bags proactively spilled: 0
Total records proactively spilled: 0
```

but it contain a data , please help me solved this error

```
grunt> a = load '/pigdata/student'; 
2016-08-07 18:10:47,529 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - fs.default.name is deprecated. Instead, use fs.defaultFS

grunt> dump a;
2016-08-07 18:13:58,694 [main] INFO     org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.ScriptState - Pig features used in the script: UNKNOWN
2016-08-07 18:13:58,752 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - fs.default.name is deprecated. Instead, use fs.defaultFS
2016-08-07 18:13:58,760 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.data.SchemaTupleBackend - Key [pig.schematuple] was not set... will not generate code.
2016-08-07 18:13:58,787 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.newplan.logical.optimizer.LogicalPlanOptimizer - {RULES_ENABLED=[AddForEach, ColumnMapKeyPrune, ConstantCalculator, GroupByConstParallelSetter, LimitOptimizer, LoadTypeCastInserter, MergeFilter, MergeForEach, PartitionFilterOptimizer, PredicatePushdownOptimizer, PushDownForEachFlatten, PushUpFilter, SplitFilter, StreamTypeCastInserter]}
2016-08-07 18:13:58,861 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MRCompiler - File concatenation threshold: 100 optimistic? false
2016-08-07 18:13:58,882 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MultiQueryOptimizer - MR plan size before optimization: 1
2016-08-07 18:13:58,882 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MultiQueryOptimizer - MR plan size after optimization: 1
2016-08-07 18:13:58,912 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - fs.default.name is deprecated. Instead, use fs.defaultFS
2016-08-07 18:13:58,951 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.RMProxy - Connecting to ResourceManager at nn1.cluster.com/127.0.1.1:8032
2016-08-07 18:13:59,175 [main] WARN  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop20.PigJobControl - falling back to default JobControl (not using hadoop 0.20 ?)
java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: runnerState
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredField(Class.java:2070)
at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop20.PigJobControl.<clinit>(PigJobControl.java:51)
at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.shims.HadoopShims.newJobControl(HadoopShims.java:109)
at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler.compile(JobControlCompiler.java:314)
at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher.launchPig(MapReduceLauncher.java:196)
at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.HExecutionEngine.launchPig(HExecutionEngine.java:304)
at org.apache.pig.PigServer.launchPlan(PigServer.java:1390)
at org.apache.pig.PigServer.executeCompiledLogicalPlan(PigServer.java:1375)
at org.apache.pig.PigServer.storeEx(PigServer.java:1034)
at org.apache.pig.PigServer.store(PigServer.java:997)
at org.apache.pig.PigServer.openIterator(PigServer.java:910)
at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.processDump(GruntParser.java:754)
at org.apache.pig.tools.pigscript.parser.PigScriptParser.parse(PigScriptParser.java:376)
at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:230)
at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:205)
at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt.run(Grunt.java:66)
at org.apache.pig.Main.run(Main.java:565)
at org.apache.pig.Main.main(Main.java:177)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)

2016-08-07 18:13:59,180 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.mapreduce.MRScriptState - Pig script settings are added to the job
2016-08-07 18:13:59,186 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - mapred.job.reduce.markreset.buffer.percent is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.reduce.markreset.buffer.percent
2016-08-07 18:13:59,186 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler - mapred.job.reduce.markreset.buffer.percent is not set, set to default 0.3
2016-08-07 18:13:59,186 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - mapred.output.compress is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.output.fileoutputformat.compress
2016-08-07 18:13:59,190 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler - This job cannot be converted run in-process
2016-08-07 18:13:59,728 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler - Added jar file:/home/rahul/pig-0.15.0/pig-0.15.0-core-h1.jar to DistributedCache through /tmp/temp2089874168/tmp1533833857/pig-0.15.0-core-h1.jar
2016-08-07 18:13:59,770 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler - Added jar file:/home/rahul/pig-0.15.0/lib/automaton-1.11-8.jar to DistributedCache through /tmp/temp2089874168/tmp943896680/automaton-1.11-8.jar
2016-08-07 18:13:59,803 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler - Added jar file:/home/rahul/pig-0.15.0/lib/antlr-runtime-3.4.jar to DistributedCache through /tmp/temp2089874168/tmp-269134508/antlr-runtime-3.4.jar
2016-08-07 18:13:59,859 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler - Added jar file:/home/rahul/pig-0.15.0/lib/guava-11.0.jar to DistributedCache through /tmp/temp2089874168/tmp544132324/guava-11.0.jar
2016-08-07 18:13:59,903 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler - Added jar file:/home/rahul/pig-0.15.0/lib/joda-time-2.5.jar to DistributedCache through /tmp/temp2089874168/tmp-215578415/joda-time-2.5.jar
2016-08-07 18:13:59,953 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler - Setting up single store job
2016-08-07 18:13:59,995 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - 1 map-reduce job(s) waiting for submission.
2016-08-07 18:13:59,996 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - mapred.job.tracker.http.address is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.jobtracker.http.address
2016-08-07 18:14:00,004 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.RMProxy - Connecting to ResourceManager at nn1.cluster.com/127.0.1.1:8032
2016-08-07 18:14:00,019 [JobControl] ERROR org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.jobcontrol.JobControl - Error while trying to run jobs.
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found interface org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobContext, but class was expected
at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigOutputFormat.setupUdfEnvAndStores(PigOutputFormat.java:235)
at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigOutputFormat.checkOutputSpecs(PigOutputFormat.java:183)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.checkSpecs(JobSubmitter.java:562)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:432)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1296)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1293)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1628)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1293)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.jobcontrol.ControlledJob.submit(ControlledJob.java:335)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.jobcontrol.JobControl.run(JobControl.java:240)
at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop20.PigJobControl.run(PigJobControl.java:121)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher$1.run(MapReduceLauncher.java:276)
2016-08-07 18:14:00,020 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - 0% complete
2016-08-07 18:14:00,028 [main] WARN  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - Ooops! Some job has failed! Specify -stop_on_failure if you want Pig to stop immediately on failure.
2016-08-07 18:14:00,028 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - job null has failed! Stop running all dependent jobs
2016-08-07 18:14:00,028 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - 100% complete
2016-08-07 18:14:00,037 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.mapreduce.MRPigStatsUtil - 1 map reduce job(s) failed!
2016-08-07 18:14:00,039 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.mapreduce.SimplePigStats - Script Statistics: 
HadoopVersion   PigVersion  UserId  StartedAt   FinishedAt  Features
2.6.0   0.15.0  rahul   2016-08-07 18:13:59 2016-08-07 18:14:00 UNKNOWN

Failed!

Failed Jobs:
JobId   Alias   Feature Message Outputs

N/A a   MAP_ONLY    Message: Unexpected System Error Occured: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found interface org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobContext, but class was expected
at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigOutputFormat.setupUdfEnvAndStores(PigOutputFormat.java:235)
at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigOutputFormat.checkOutputSpecs(PigOutputFormat.java:183)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.checkSpecs(JobSubmitter.java:562)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:432)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1296)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1293)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1628)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1293)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.jobcontrol.ControlledJob.submit(ControlledJob.java:335)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.jobcontrol.JobControl.run(JobControl.java:240)
at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop20.PigJobControl.run(PigJobControl.java:121)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher$1.run(MapReduceLauncher.java:276)
hdfs://nn1.cluster.com:9000/tmp/temp2089874168/tmp539406268,


Input(s):
Failed to read data from "/pigdata/student"

Output(s):
Failed to produce result in "hdfs://nn1.cluster.com:9000/tmp/temp2089874168/tmp539406268"

Counters:
Total records written : 0
Total bytes written : 0
Spillable Memory Manager spill count : 0
Total bags proactively spilled: 0
Total records proactively spilled: 0

Job DAG:
null
```

Comment: Please share input file content (student)...and Hadoop version 0.20?

Comment: hadoop-version-2.6.0

Comment: vineet 1 hisham 2 raj 3 ajeet 4 sujit 5 ramesh 6 priya 7 priyanka 8 suresh 9 ritesh 10 hitesh 11 jatin 12 chitesh 13 suman 14 raman 15 aman 16 ravi 17 shravi 18 chavvi 19 himanshu 20 – Rahul 51 mins ago

Comment: what is PIG version?

Comment: hadoop-version-2.6.0

Comment: in your data set u r having multiple sapce or tab in between name and id?

Answer (score 1):

```
--Please follow the below steps..
-- to start the pig in local mode

$pig -x local 
grunt> A = load 'student';
grunt> dump A

--Please let me know if your issue not resolved.
```

Answer (score 0):

it seems you have not set the `HADOOP_HOME` in your environment, that is why `PIG` is trying to use its default hadoop version `0.20`:

warning below in your log indicates that:

`org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop20.PigJobControl - falling back to default`

also error: `Added jar file:/home/rahul/pig-0.15.0/pig-0.15.0-core-h1.jar`
indicates that `PIG` is using h1.jar  - [download the h2.jar from Maven](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.apache.pig%22%20AND%20a%3A%22pig%22) and replace it in your PIG installation to proper location.

add/edit `$HADOOP_HOME` to `2.6.0` installation dir, and re-run the `PIG` grunt shell:

Your pig statement should be like this (assuming `student` file is `\t` delimited and has three fields)

```
 a = load '/pigdata/student' USING PigStorage('\t') as (name:chararray,id:int);
```

Answer (score 0):

Same issue i was also facing like:
Input(s):
Failed to read data from "/pigdata/student"

Output(s):
Failed to produce result in "hdfs://nn1.cluster.com:9000/tmp/temp2089874168/tmp539406268"

When you have placed the file in hdfs and you are facing the issue while load the file in bag so do one thing .. Try to change the port number when the correct port numb will be shown ******in failed to produce result in******

Due to some port number issue you can face the prob s make sure first you have to check the port number along with correct path.